# __str__ dunder method for OOP Python class still returns <__main__. object > instead of string

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to define a class and have it return a properly formatted string. However, it returns the same `<__main__.Card object at 0x7fb4439e4d00>` result as when I print the class without the **str** dunder method. I assume that it has something to do with the fact that I pass no parameters into the class in the first place. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = "diamond"
        self.fill = random.choice(fill)
        self.number = random.choice(number)
        self.color = random.choice(color)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.number}-{self.color}-{self.fill}-{self.shape}.png"

x = Card()
print(x)
print(x.__str__())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation of `__str__` method is wrong.
Your code should be:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = "diamond"
        self.fill = random.choice(fill)
        self.number = random.choice(number)
        self.color = random.choice(color)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.number}-{self.color}-{self.fill}-{self.shape}.png"


x = Card()
print(x)
print(str(x))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel like a dummy. Sometimes you just need new eyes on a problem.

Comment: No problem at all :) can you please vote the answer and set as solved?

Comment: And of course you don't use `print(x.__str__())` but `print(str(x))`.